# Trying to switch activity when screen touched

Tags: java, android, android-intent, ontouchlistener

I'm new to java. I'm experienced in C++ but have decided to pick up Java so I can develop on android :)

I am trying to implement a simple function which switches the activity to my game activity when the screen is pressed.

```
public class OpeningScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    // create the screen state
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_opening_screen);

        // create the on touch listener
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.opening_layout);

        layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(OpeningScreen.this, GameScreen.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I grasp the idea of what this is doing but it doesn't seem to work and I feel like there is something little that I've missed out or not quite understood when programming this.

If anyone could give me some assistance that would be great! :)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what the issue is, what "doesn't seem to work?" Is the activity not starting or are you not seeing the listener event fire off? I'd recommend first seeing if the event fires off, and if it's the activity not starting, then what does your activity do? It may be an issue in your GameScreen setup maybe?

Comment: @Yoshi_64 The error is that the '@Override' doesn't override method from it's superclass. I'm not sure what that means, I'm assuming it means it doesn't get called, but why?

Comment: Just realized, the method is `protected` and not `public` so I think that's your issue? If you are using Android Studio press `Ctrl+O` and you'll see a list of methods you can Override. Look for `onCreate(Bundle)` type you are implementing, and see if it implements it correctly, or make the change to `public` from `protected` and see if that helps.

Comment: @Yoshi_64 there is no methods I can override when I do that command on the piece of code. I think it has something to do with `new layout.setOnTouchListener()` as it says it 'cannot resolve symbol.' Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: Ok, if it doesn't appear it means then you are currently implementing it. The command shows unimplemented Overrides you can use. Also try editing the line `layout.setOnTouchListener( new OnTouchListener() {` instead of `layout.setOnTouchListener( new layout.setOnTouchListener()` Also no problem. :)

Comment: @Yoshi_64 I've made the edits to the code that got rid of all the ide errors and such I was getting. Now it all works, but when I run it, it runs on my android and then before any of this code is executed. It comes up with the error 'Move! has stopped' and crashes. Any idea?

Comment: You'll have to get output from the device from ADB. It sounds like you have a fatal crash, that should be printed out from the logs. Connect your device and debug it with Android Studio, then look for the stacktrace in your output.

Comment: Okay after running the debugging process I have come up with this running exception `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dylanmorgan.move/com.dylanmorgan.move.OpeningScreen}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout`     `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout`

Comment: @Yoshi_64 So surely this means that there is something wrong with the relative layout/constraint layout?

Comment: @Yoshi_64 I changed the relative layout to constraint layout and the whole thing works perfectly. So thank you :)

Comment: Awesome, good to hear :) Good luck on your learning experience and happy coding!